# Finding strings with a specific pattern but not already found in a list (Java regex)

Tags: java, regex

I have a String:

```
String line = "9.99\t8.29\tAB=0.0;CD=0.0;EF=0.0;GH=0.0;LI=0.0;JK=0.0";
```

And I have a list of labels:

```
String[] labels = new String[] {"AB","EF","LI","JK"};
```

A label match means it matches the following pattern `"\\b"+label+"="`

I need to find out if there are any other labels besides the ones in the list. Note that the label names are not always 2 characters long, should be one or more characters `[a-zA-Z]+`.

In the above example, labels other than the specified ones in the labels list, are: "CD" and "GH"

I don't know the label names "CD" and "GH" beforehand, so can't simply look for them like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+"CD"+"=");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
```

Note that the output should be the names of the labels not in the list, i.e. "CD" and "GH" in the above example

Comment: You should have a general pattern for the name of the labels, then match all of them, pick out those you recognize, and those you don't among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "9.99\t8.29\tAB=0.0;CD=0.0;EF=0.0;GH=0.0;LI=0.0;JK=0.0";
        String[] labels = new String[]{"AB", "EF", "LI", "JK"};
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]+=");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        while (m.find()) {
            String groupName = m.group(0).substring(0,m.group(0).length()-1);
            if (Arrays.asList(labels).contains(groupName)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.println(groupName);
            }
        }
    }
```

It will remove the last character (`=`) after finding group and then check whether it it already there in your array and then prints it if it is not. The output is:

`CD
GH`

Answer (score 0):

Oops looks like I'm answering my own question, although I'm not sure if this is the best way. Would welcome better answers or suggestions?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashSet<String> unseenLabels = new HashSet<String>();
        String line = "9.99\t8.29\tAB=0.0;CD=0.0;EF=0.0;GH=0.0;LI=0.0;JK=0.0";
        String[] labels = new String[] {".AB=",".EF=",".LI=",".JK="}; //Label with a dot at the beginning to prevent AB= and AAB= getting confused, for example

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]+=");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        while (m.find())
        {
            for(int i=0; i< labels.length; i++) {
                if(!Arrays.asList(labels).contains(("." + m.group()))) unseenLabels.add(m.group());
            }
        }

        for(String unseenLabel: unseenLabels) {
            System.out.println(unseenLabel.substring(0,unseenLabel.length()-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
CD
GH
```

Comment: `List.contains` should evaluate by `equals`, so your `.` hack should not be necessary